# Select and Hover Specific anchor tag

Tags: css

```css
.fa-free-code-camp:hover{
   transform: rotate(0deg);
   transition: all 0.3s ease;
   color: #1B5E20;
}

.fa:hover {
   transform: rotate(0deg);
   transition: all 0.3s ease;
   color: #1A237E;
 }
        
 .fa{
   font-size: 30px;
   transform: rotate(-25deg);
   transition: all 0.5s ease;
 }
```

```html
<div role="navigation">
   <nav class="nav nav-inline  ">
  <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa  fa-linkedin-square large-class " aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-github large-class" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
  <a class="nav-link " href="#"><i class="fa fa-link large-class" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
   <a class="nav-link " href="#"><i class="fa fa-free-code-camp large-class" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
</nav>       
</div>
```

### #

How can I target the fa-free-code-camp:hover specific only while others are as per the code instruction. I just want the colour to be different for this example.

Comment: you can give it another class like <i class="fa fa-free-code-camp test"></i> and then in the css you can give .fa-free-code-camp.test:hover

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that you have two rules with the same [specificity](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/) and so the later rule overrides the prior rule.

Either change the order of the rules such that `.fa-free-code-camp:hover` comes after `.fa:hover`, or increase the specificity of `.fa-free-code-camp:hover` to `.fa.fa-free-code-camp:hover`.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
.fa.fa-free-code-camp:hover{
   transform: rotate(0deg);
   transition: all 0.3s ease;
   color: #1B5E20;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have changed position of your style declaration and also if you want to apply new css on already applied css you need to specify both the classes there

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/rk942mbe/1/) is a jsFiddle for working example. And below is a css code you can check different.

```
.fa{
    font-size: 30px;
    transform: rotate(25deg);
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.fa:hover {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    color: #1A237E;
}
.fa.fa-free-code-camp:hover{
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```